# Replacing c# function bij Jquery not working without knowing how to troubleshoot

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to replace an ASP.NET (C#) server-sided method by an javascript/Jquery method. I'm fairly new to Jquery but all went well until I began with regular expressions.

my code in ASP.NET C#

```
if ((Regex.Match(postcode.Trim(), @"^[1-9]\d{3} ?[a-zA-Z]{2}$")).Success)
    {
       return Regex.Replace(postcode.Trim(), @"(^[1-9]\d{3})( ?)([a-zA-Z]{2}$)", "$1$3").ToUpper();
    }
    else
    {
       throw new Exception("Postcode incorrect");
    }
```

in Jquery I'm only focussing to replace for the moment by manually input the right strings.

I've created a function like:

```
function FormatDutchPostalCode() {
   var postcode = $("#Text1").val();
   postcode = postcode.replace(/(^[1-9]\d{3})( ?)([a-zA-Z]{2}$)/, $1$3);
   $("#Text1").val(postcode);
}
```

I'm getting the value from the textbox, so far so good. But when replacing it seems the browsers exits the function (tested in IE9 and FF10.0.1)

What I'm i doing wrong and is it possible to troubleshoot Jquery/Javascript. I've seen firebug could set breakpoints but I can't find if (and if so which) errors occur.

Comment: Look in firebug's console tab. All JavaScript errors are displayed there.

Comment: The browser exits a javascript function when there is an error, so ultimately you should have an error displayed in your console. Try to put this console.log("hello world") after your call to the replace method. It will output to the firebug console. If this doesnt show up, then your regex isnt formated correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a port of your C# function to JS. It uses an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) in order to cache the regex without polluting the current execution scope.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/musicisair/Sqbca/)

```
var FormatDutchPostalCode = (function() {
    var reg = /^([1-9]\d{3})\s?([a-z]{2})$/i;
    return function(){
        var postcode = $.trim($("#Text1").val());
        if (postcode && postcode.match(reg) )
        {
            return postcode.replace(reg, "$1$2").toUpperCase();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Error("Postcode incorrect");
        }
    };
}());
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `'$1$3'` or `/$1$3/` for the replacement pattern. Currently you've placed the replacement pattern in without using it as a string or regex pattern.

Check out this [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/LdQ2N/) showing a working solution.

You could also simplify your pattern by removing the capture group for the optional space, then you can perform the replace using the existing capture groups:

- Pattern: `/^([1-9]\d{3}) ?([a-zA-Z]{2})$/`
- Replacement: `'$1$2'` (only 2 groups exist)

To use Firebug or developer tools, you should be able to bring the tool up using the <kbd>F12</kbd> key. You can test your replacement directly in the console window, or debug your script from the script tab (select the relevant JavaScript file) and place a breakpoint on the line you're interested in by right clicking and adding it or clicking on the line number on the left.

Check out this article for more details: [JavaScript debugging for beginners](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners).